# OpenAPI 3.0 specifications - validating an array that is not required, but has minItems=1

Tags: openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

```
optionalids:
  type: array
  items:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Id'
  minItems: 1
```

optionalIds is included inside another complex-type. and optionalIds is not a "required" property
Using openapi-codegen to generate code along with beanValidations.

The validation checks for the array optionalIds to at least contain one element. Since this is not a required property, not passing the optionalIds in the request should go through fine.
Is this understanding correct ?

What should be done to beanValidation templates so that this works

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: In which language you are generating the code and what are the codegen configuration you are using?